# Autolayout with image view, 2 labels, button - the labels disappear after rotating

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout, sdwebimage

In a simple [test app for iPhone](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyPhone) I am trying to display a user phone in an image view (using SDWebImage through CocoaPods), two labels and a "Play" button - each UI element underneath other as shown in the screenshot:

[image: app screenshot]

I am using Autolayout in Xcode 5 and set 20px around each UI element as shown in the screenshot (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXNZe.png)):

[image: Xcode 5 screenshot]

My code in [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/MyPhone/MyPhone/ViewController.m) is short and simple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _firstName.text = @"Alex";
    _city.text      = @"Bochum";

    [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Male.png"]];
}
```

Unfortunately my problem is that after rotation both labels disappear:

[image: landscape screenshot]

[image: portrait screenshot]

Why does it happen? I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out, tried changing the "Content Hugging Priority" and "Content Compression Resistance Priority" for various UI elements too...

Comment: You have some errors or missing constraints-- see that little red arrow in the circle in the scene list of your storyboard? Click that arrow to see what the errors you have and try to fix them.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have red triangle [in my app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/MyPhone) - that screenshot was taken in the process of creating the test app. In the final version I don't have the red triangle, but the problem is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved my problem by giving lower "Content Hugging Priority" and "Content Compression Resistance Priority" to the image view (set everything to 250, here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fyc6.png)) and higher - to the both labels and button (set them to 750):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

(Also for the image view I've changed the mode to "Aspect Fill" and enabled "Clip Subviews") and now it works ok:

[image: portrait screenshot]

[image: landscape screenshot]

Being an iOS programming newbie, I'm sorry if my question has been too simple, but that what seems to have resolved it (moving `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` call to `viewDidAppear` did not). Also sorry for having my face 5 times at this web page - that image had the problem in the test app, so I didn't bother to search for a neutral one.

Answer (score 0):

1- i think your problem is that your using an simulator with  an 3.5 inch screen , try using an 4 inch screen or an ipad simulator if you want.

2-the reason i think they disappear is that there is no room for them, try to make the SDWebImage smaller .

3-also in your storyboard if you click on the label itself and go to the first tab (file inspector)you can see an option that says use AutoLayuot see if you have that checked or not since it might be the problem.

i hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how your suggestions help: I want my app to work with both 3.5 and 4 inch iPhones and I am using Autolayout as stated in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are okay, this seems to be a bug in SDWebImage. While the image you want is downloading, the placeholder is displayed correctly (labels are visible). However, once the image is downloaded something strange happens while replacing the placeholder with your image and your layout goes bad. If you call

```
[_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar];
```

instead of

```
[_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Male.png"]];
```

it's doing what it's supposed to.

Update:
You need to call

```
    [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAvatar]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Male.png"]];
```

inside viewDidAppear for constraints to take effect. So this might not be SDWebImageBug after all :)

Comment: Thank you - I've moved the `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` call to `viewDidAppear`, but the issue is still present.

Comment: Ah, now i get it :) I cloned your project and made these changes in storyboard: set vertical compression resistance of labels and button to 1000 and ImageView to 750 ... this ensures that first thing to shrink is the image view and not the labels (their height was 0 after rotation thanks to compression resistance being the same as image view)